# Preview for image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have here the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70LLLrdg/2/) to see what I want. Here I have functions for an Android webView to open camera. And what I want is when i'm selecting the image from gallery to make a preview for image. Using the same function with simple input `type='file'` everything works fine, it's making the preview, but using functions from android to open camera, won't work. Anyone can help me?

Here is exactly the function for preview

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files.length) {
        console.log(input.files.length);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $(input).siblings('img.img-upload').prop('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".input-upload").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
    console.log(this.id);
});
```